# What is the right way to implement authentication between a WordPress plugin and a Laravel API?

Tags: wordpress, laravel, authentication, api-design

I'm so confused about how to get authentication between an external, consumer website and a Laravel API right.  What I'd like is to have a web app for which users are able to present information from the app to other people, using an external website that consumes the app's API.  Here's an example of the basic setup in a bit more detail:

- A Laravel 5.3 app that has a protected API endpoint `api/status`.  Only authenticated users should be able to hit `api/status`, and the status returned is a particular status for the authenticated user.
- An external website that consumes the Laravel API on behalf of a user, let's call her Alice.  The necessary information is stored in the backend of Alice's website so that it can authenticate with the API on behalf of Alice.  (The actual implementation I'm working on will be a WordPress site, and the API consumption will be done by a WordPress plugin that I am implementing; so any info stored will likely be stored in the WordPress database.)
- The website has a `/status` page that displays Alice's status to anyone who browses to the page.  (Ie, when the `/status` page is browsed to, an API call to the app is made on behalf of Alice.  The returned status is specific to Alice, and is displayed to the person browsing the page.)  People browsing to `/status` on Alice's website do NOT need to do any sort of authenticating to view the status on the page.

That is very simplified compared to my actual goal, but I hope it serves to keep the extraneous details to a minimum so we can focus on my actual question, which is **what method of authentication should I use to achieve this?**

One thing I DON'T want:

- The person browsing Alice's website should NOT be able to use their browser's inspector to watch the API call and from that create further API calls on Alice's behalf on their own.

I have Passport installed on my Laravel App, but if I'm understanding things correctly I don't want to use the basic Access Token issuing workflow, as that would require the people browsing to Alice's website to authenticate using the Alices's credentials.  For the same reason, I don't think I want an Implicit Grant Token.

Using a Password Grant Token would require storing Alice's password for the Laravel app on her website.  Is it ok to store passwords like this in a WordPress database?  It makes me nervous...

The other option available through Passport is to have Alice create a Personal Access Token and store that in her website backend as the token to use to authenticate.  But the Laravel documentation seems to imply that Personal Access Tokens are meant for testing and development purposes, which makes me wary of going this route for a production plugin.  Plus, doesn't using a PAT make it possible to do the thing I DON'T want above, since the PAT is simply passed in the request header?  Or is that problem mitigated by the fact that the API interaction would be done over SSL?

Do I even need to go through Passport to achieve what I want here?  Is there a better way?

I've been reading myself in circles trying to understand what the best practice for this kind of setup is.  I'm sorry if this question isn't focused enough, but if anyone has any good advice, or can clarify things for me I would much appreciate it!